# Is this SPF record valid?

Tags: spf

I just want to confirm if my SPF record is valid :

```
v=spf1 ip4:66.46.182.1/24 ip4:206.132.164.176/24 ip4:23.21.63.174 -all
```

Will 2 ip ranges and a specific ip on one line valid??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly valid. Subnets and single IPs as well as other categories are valid and in fact *must* be on one line. You're only allowed by the RFC to publish one SPF RR (and one TXT equivalent)

There's a very useful test utility here, where you can check it for yourself before making it live: http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html